# Help with making pavlova bases

Tags: baking

I constantly am having problems with the removal of baking paper used to line baking tray when making Pavlova bases. I have tried oiling the tray and then dusting the baking paper with cornflour to make it easier to remove the baking paper  from the cooked Pavlova base, but it always sticks and tends to destroy the base. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post your recipe and technique.

Answer (score 2):

Pan release spray (such as PAM in the US) can help hold the paper in place (to aid your piping) and prevent the finished meringue from sticking to the paper once cooled. I've used this technique in both professional kitchens and in my own kitchen at home.

Spray a light coating on the pan, then lay down the paper.

If necessary, spread the coating evenly with your fingers or a towel (for some reasons, the consumer/home versions of these products often emit more of a "blast" compared to the finer "mist" of the professional ones).

Then repeat the process on the top side of the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use edible paper. That would probably be the easiest and quickest way to solve this issue. You can even make it yourself:

https://makezine.com/projects/make-edible-paper-3-easy-steps/

Answer (score 1):

We've always used [teflon sheet](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Reusable-Teflon-Cooking-stick-guarantee/dp/B001TKYTMA) for pavlova. It peels off the cool pavlova very well. It's reusable and useful for many other things too, and goes through the dishwasher (though it's slightly awkward in there).  Just cut it to the size of your baking tray with scissors.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you use waxed side of paper and dry base long enough? I know it may be stupid but my girlfriend always mix the sides and her dough always stick to paper.

When making base from 4 large whites I preheat oven to 120C. The I bake the base for 30 minutes AND dry for at least 3 hours in 90-100C.
My mother used to draw circle with her nail in the paper where base should end. She said it help to separate base from paper but I think it was need because of the poor paper quality (she was using white sheets when I use much thicker brown paper from roll).